# empty path name is not legal when i save images c# windows Application

Tags: c#

i want to save multiple Images now when I save all the 2 images I get no exception...
but when I try to save only 1 or 2 or  its throws an exception "Empty Path is not legal".
my code is here

```
  byte[] img = null;
  FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgloc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
  img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

  //

  byte[] img1 = null;
  FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(imgloc1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  BinaryReader br1 = new BinaryReader(fs1);
  img1 = br1.ReadBytes((int)fs1.Length);


  //
  con.Open();
  SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into easypaisa (trid,selectopt,smobile,rmobile,snic,rnic,tamount,tcharges,totalcharges,date,descr,inv_no,Company,user_name,sprof,dataimg,image2) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "','" + textBox10.Text + "','" + textBox9.Text + "','" + comboBox2.Text + "','" + Get_User_label.Text + "','" + textBox13.Text + "',@dataimg,@image2)", con);
  cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dataimg", img));
  cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@image2", img1));
  cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();

  MessageBox.Show("Data Saved successfully", "Important Message",
                   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Comment: How do you manage to save only one image with this code? You are always trying to read both files. There is no conditional to skip one image or the other.

Comment: The cause of your error would be in the code that initializes `imgloc` and `imgloc1`, which you don't put in your question. Set a breakpoint at `FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgloc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);` and see if `imgloc` is what you expect. Trace it back to where it comes from. Repeat the same for `imgloc1`.

Comment: @jdphenix I think he is intentionally leaving one of the two path variables empty (thus the error message) but he should consider this fact in the code above.

Comment: @Steve That makes sense.

Comment: Steve im new in programing i dont know how can i skip condition

Answer (score 0):

Add validation for file path before read the file

```
  byte[] img = null;
  if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(imgloc){
     FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgloc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
     BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
  }


  byte[] img1 = null;
  if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(imgloc1){
     FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(imgloc1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
     BinaryReader br1 = new BinaryReader(fs1);
     img1 = br1.ReadBytes((int)fs1.Length);
  }
```

also set DBNull value for the image parameters because now they can be null

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dataimg", img?? DBNull.Value));
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@image2", img1?? DBNull.Value));
```

Comment: cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dataimg", img?? DBNull.Value));
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@image2", img1?? DBNull.Value));

Comment: cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dataimg", img?? DBNull.Value));
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@image2", img1?? DBNull.Value));
here is error come Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type'byte[]' and system.DBnull